# Help identifying mothball/raddish-like plants/fungi?

Tags: soil

I was digging a hole to plant a tree in the middle of a large oregano patch that's been growing on top of an old compost pile.  I found a about 20 or 30 mothball-like/white raddish-like objects (plants? fungi?) growing deep in the soil.  Can anyone tell me what they might be?  Thank you.[image]

Comment: Size? Are they stiff or spongey? Did you cut any of them open? What does the inside look like? Any smell?

Comment: Looks like they are tubers e,g, potatoes. There are countless  plants that set down tubers from which new plants can grow from and maybe give some thought to what was growing out of the old compost heap along with the oregano, then you will have the name of the plant. They look healthy, so maybe if you have a spare container, pop them into it with some of that matured compost and find out later in the year. Surprise plants are always a joy. Heck they could even be 'just' potatoes for all we know.

Comment: @BobaFit @ Boba Fit: They are firm and crisp. I did not cut them open but I will.

Comment: @Nikki Aha! Yes. They must be tubers. Thank you! I don't think there ever were potatoes in that area but I did grow a variety of vegetables there years ago. And yes I will plant them in a container. :-)

Comment: They kind of look like the things that puffballs come from (sorry, it's late and my "science" has deserted me).